# Create a list with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have an class called `message`, inside which I have a `IEnumerable` called `copies`.

I need to create a new `Recipient` class object with the copies `content`.

In order to do that, I created a `Recipient` list, then interacting on `copies` using `ForEach` method; But I took so much code lines, and it doesn't feel good for me. There is a way to do that using `LINQ` methods?

I'll put below what I've done so far.

**CODE USING FOREACH (PROPERLY WORKING)**

```
var recipientListWithForEach = new List<Recipient>();

foreach (var item in message.Copies)
{
    recipientListWithForEach.Add(new Recipient
    {
        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
        {
            Address = item
        }
    });
}
```

**CODE USING LINQ (NOT WORKING, IDK WHY)**

```
var recipientListWithLINQ = new List<Recipient> {
    message.Copies.Select(item => new Recipient {
        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress {
            Address = item
        }
    });
};
```

Giving the error message:

> not possible convert from "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.Graph.Recipient>" to "Microsoft.Graph.Recipient"

Comment: what exactly does "not working" mean? We can´t see your error...

Comment: Edited adding error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a little bit too much work! `.Select` returns the list you need. Wrapping that list in a `Recipient` constructor is not needed.

```
var recipientListWithLINQ =
    message.Copies.Select(item => new Recipient {
        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress {
            Address = item
        }
    });
```

Comment: It worked exactly as i needed. Thanks for explanation @catfood. You saved my day!

Comment: note that if you want a list, you need to add `.ToList()` at the end

Answer (score 2):

Actually problem that you have not used proper constructor for List

```cs
// working
new List<T>(items)
```

Following is list initialisation syntax, which accepts not an IEnumerable but single items separated by coma.

```cs
// bad
new List<T> {items}
// working
new List<T> {item1, item2}
```

So, just correct your code

```cs
var recipientListWithLINQ = new List<Recipient> (
    message.Copies.Select(item => new Recipient {
        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress {
            Address = item
        }
    ));
};
```

But LINQ query should be simplier

```cs
var recipientListWithLINQ = 
    message.Copies.Select(item => new Recipient {
        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress {
            Address = item
        }
    )
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Update per comment: since you need single item, you don't really need IEnumerable. Just pick first item from `Copies` and construct your `Recipient`. And probably pick a better name for a variable?

```
var item = message.Copies.First();
var recipientListWithLINQ = new Recipient {
    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress {
        Address = item
    }
};
```

Original answer:

You need to convert your IEnumerable to List with ToList()

```
var recipientListWithLINQ = message.Copies.Select(item => new Recipient {
    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress {
        Address = item
    }
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Didn't work. I need to send the plain Recipient here. Not a list of ones

Comment: @HudsonMedeiros That comment is a little confusing since in the question you have sample code that creates a list of recipients and it's titled **"(PROPERLY WORKING)"**, and the original code in this answer did the same thing, except using linq, which is what the question was asking for.

Comment: @RufusL way more confusing is how accepted answer worked for OP, and mine - not..

Comment: Yeah, they were identical except you included `.ToList()`, which is what they asked for.